# VB.NET DataSet not working with view with linked SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, odbc, odbc-sql-server-driver

I am in DataGrid hell right now but that's another post.

Anyway, I wrote a view with a union query in SQL Server that grabs data from a linked SQL server.

Anytime I try to add this object as a dataset in VB.NET it completely bombs out on me with this ugly error message...

ERROR [42000] [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver] [SQL Server] The operation could not be performed because the OLE DB Provider 'SQLOLEDB' was unable to begin a distributed transaction. ERROR [01000] [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver] [SQL Server] [OLE/DB provider returned message : new transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator] ERROR [01000] [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver] [SQL Server] OLE DB Error Trace [OLE/DB Provider 'SQLOLEDB' lTransactionJoin::JoinTransaction returned 0x8004d00a]

I'm completely stumped as to why I can't create a dataset from a view that references a linked SQL server.  It's not this specific view either, all views that reference this linked server bomb out.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server and what O/S is the linked server running on?

Comment: Both servers are Windows 2003 Server and the linked server is SQL 2008 and the from server is SQL 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple answer is to [enable MSDTC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817064) on the servers. As to why this is happening on your views, I'm not entirely sure. There are also some good trouble shooting tips [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306843/en-us).

Comment: Yeah, that did it.  Man, who knew?  Besides you of course =)  How unnecessarily cryptic.